# IN .Net 2.0 C# Passing Datatable to Stored Prodedure Ocured Error

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, sqldbtype

System.ArgumentException: No mapping exists from DbType {0} to a known {1}.    at System.Data.SqlClient.MetaType.GetMetaType(Object value)    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter.set_Value(Object value)

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

When passing a DataTable from c# to SQL Server, make sure you have a User-Defined table type created.  The data type and length of each column in the table type must match exactly the data types of each column in your data table in c#.

[image]

If you ere passing the table to a stored procedure as an input parameter, it can look something like this:

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[usp_MyStoredProc]

@Var1 date,
@Var2 varchar(8),
@MyInputTable as dbo.MyUserDefinedTableType READONLY

AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Stored pcedure code ...
```

Comment: Correct ,Done as same,Error came on C#.Net (Smart Device) Application.

Comment: Used this  -cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TANLE_Temp", SqlDbType.Udt).Value = dt_Teemp;

Comment: Use SqlDbType.Structured, do not use SqlDbType.Udt.